# NDJSON array import to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to import ndjson files with several array objects into elasticsearch. File contents are like this

```
{"uyt":[{"id": 28,"Title": "sdfg"}, {"id": 56,"Title": "rtwret"}]}
{"khg":[{"id": 45,"Title": "sdfg"}, {"id": 5,"Title": "rtwret"}]}
{"ihu":[{"id": 63,"Title": "iuy"}]}
{"bvc":[{"id": 8,"Title": "hvhbi"}, {"id": 6,"Title": "kytd"}, {"id": 89,"Title": "resa"}]}
```

Problem is that elasticsearch does not seem to recognize these arrays. Import ends with blank page.

Any idea what is wrong here?